# How to make shell script to automatically input value

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting, automation

I'm trying to copy ssh public key to all hosts on my network with the following little script

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(nmap -n -sn 192.0.2.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'); do
  ssh-copy-id vagrant@$ip
done
```

However, it asks for the password for each IP, which count is unknown until execution of the script. How to make this script to automatically enter the password (which in this case is same for all the hosts)?

Comment: You want [tag:expect]. Hunt around this site for expect/ssh questions, and you'll find lots of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sshpass`. Note that it is not a good idea to store passwords in the scripts, but it will do the job for the setup:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(nmap -n -sn 192.0.2.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'); do
  sshpass -p password ssh-copy-id vagrant@$ip
done
```